# How to split css from the style.css using MiniCssExtractPlugin?

Tags: webpack, sass, mini-css-extract-plugin

I'm trying to transform two of my `.scss` files into two different `.css` files: one called `timer_player.css` and another called `style.css`.

The `style.css` can't have any style of `timer_player.css`.

With `ExtractTextPlugin` I can to this by creating two instances, but this package is deprecated.

My folder tree looks something like this:

```
- src
  - js
    - popup.js
    - content_scripts
      - timer_player
        - index.js
  - css
    - popup.css
    - timer_player.css
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this after a long reading through this [Issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/45). Part of the trick is to use the `optimization` attribute and filter by the chunk name.

My webpack.config.js look something like this now:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    popup: ['./src/js/popup.js', './src/css/popup.scss'],
    timer_player: [
      './src/js/content_scripts/timer_player/index.js',
      './src/css/timer_player.scss',
    ],
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: '.',
    path: resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },
  plugins: [
    new WebpackReloaderPlugin({
      port: 9090, // Which port use to create the server
      reloadPage: true, // Force the reload of the page also
      entries: {
        // The entries used for the content/background scripts
        contentScript: 'popup', // Use the entry names, not the file name or the path
        background: 'background', // *REQUIRED
      },
    }),

    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: '[name].css' }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'popup.html'),
      filename: 'popup.html',
      chunks: ['popup'],
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: './src/manifest.json' },
      { from: './src/images', to: 'images' },
    ]),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              includePaths: ['node_modules', 'node_modules/@material/*']
                .map(d => path.join(__dirname, d))
                .map(g => glob.sync(g))
                .reduce((a, c) => a.concat(c), []),
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.txt$/,
        use: 'raw-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        extractPopupStyles: {
          name: 'style',
          chunks: chunk => chunk.name === 'popup',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Any suggestions are welcome